# Proving the sequence $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I know the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of a limit in this case is $\forall \epsilon >0 \exists N\in \mathbb{N}\forall n \in \mathbb{N} (n \geq N \implies \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}<\epsilon)$.

So far, I have been able to show: $$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}.$$

This is the part where I find myself stuck. What do I need to do next?

Comment: "For all integers" is a peculiar phrase here. It converges as $n\to\infty$, but that is different that saying "for all integers."

Comment: I agree with @Thomas Andrews. I correct for you this language "peculiarity" (I would say "misnaming").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you can write your last line is $\leq\frac{1}{2\sqrt n}$ which will be less than $\epsilon$ for $n > \frac{1}{4\epsilon^2}$

Answer (score 0):

You are starting well.

Since $$\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n\geq \sqrt n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}+\infty$$

you can conclude that

$$\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}+\infty$$

because there is no indeterminate form for the limit anymore.

So

$$\frac 1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a function such that
$f'(x) \to 0$
as
$x \to \infty$
then
$f(x+1)-f(x)
\to 0$
as
$x \to \infty$.

Proof.

By the mean value theorem,
$f(x+1)-f(x)
=f'(c)
$
where
$x \le c \le x+1$.

Now let
$f(x) = \sqrt{x}$.
$f'(x) = \dfrac1{2\sqrt{x}}
\to 0$
as $x \to \infty$.